# cmake arguments passed to scripts on command line

Tags: cmake, cmake-language

I was just reading the book [Modern CMake for C++](https://www.packtpub.com/product/modern-cmake-for-c/9781801070058), and on page 55, the author says exactly this:

> Remember that you can pass arguments to scripts through the command line after a `--` token. Values will be stored in the `CMAKE_ARGV<n>` variable and the count of the passed arguments will be in the `CMAKE_ARGC` variable.

so I tried the following script:

```
# file.cmake
message("CMAKE_ARGC=${CMAKE_ARGC}")

set (i 0)
while(i LESS CMAKE_ARGC)
  message("CMAKE_ARGV${i}=${CMAKE_ARGV${i}}")
  math(EXPR i "${i}+1")
endwhile()
```

from [here](https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/issues/1607), and I ran this command:

```bash
cmake -P file.cmake -- arg
```

but the output was:

```
CMAKE_ARGC=5
CMAKE_ARGV0=cmake
CMAKE_ARGV1=-P
CMAKE_ARGV2=file.cmake
CMAKE_ARGV3=--
CMAKE_ARGV4=arg
```

Does the author of [Modern CMake for C++](https://www.packtpub.com/product/modern-cmake-for-c/9781801070058) say that the script arguments starts after `--` (which he's clearly WRONG) or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact text there, maybe the author is wrong, maybe you lost some context and misread that. `--` does not mean that the args before `--` will not be stored in `CMAKE_ARGV<n>`. It means only that any options after `--` are not parsed by CMake.

If you run you script like `cmake -P file.cmake -Dvar=val`, you get `CMAKE_ARGV3=-Dvar=val` in the output and the variable `${var}` in the script.

If you run you script like `cmake -P file.cmake -- -Dvar=val`, you get `CMAKE_ARGV4=-Dvar=val` in the output and no variable `${var}` defined in the script.